# Kafka Stream to Spark Stream using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, stream-processing

We have Kafka stream which use Avro. I need to connect it to Spark Stream using python.

I used bellow code to do that:

```
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, topic, {'bootstrap.servers': brokers}, valueDecoder=decoder)
```

Then I got bellow error.

> An error occurred while calling o44.awaitTermination.
>
> 2018-10-11 15:58:01 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 3 failed: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:149, took 1.403049 s
>
> 2018-10-11 15:58:01 INFO  JobScheduler:54 - Finished job streaming job 1539253680000 ms.0 from job set of time 1539253680000 ms
>
> 2018-10-11 15:58:01 ERROR JobScheduler:91 - Error running job streaming job 1539253680000 ms.0
>
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/XXXXXX/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 65, in call
>
> r = self.func(t, *rdds)
>
> File "/XXXXXX/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py", line 171, in takeAndPrint
>
> taken = rdd.take(num + 1)
>
> File "/XXXXXX/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1375, in take
>
> res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
>
> File "/XXXXXX/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 1013, in runJob
>
> sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
>
> File "/XXXXXX/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**
>
> answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
>
> File "/XXXXXX/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
>
> format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 8, gen-CLUSTER_NODE, executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't connect to leader for topic TOPIC_NAME 1: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

However before this error display on terminal and terminate the process i was able to get print a RDD by using bellow code

```
kvs.pprint()
```

What is leader? How can we over come this?

Comment: A leader is the Kafka server handling the request... Are you sure Kafka is running and you can reach the server from the Spark jobs?

Comment: Yes, I can consume it using normal python confluent kafka consumer.

Comment: And your Spark cluster has no firewall or other network issues that would be any different from that code?

Comment: I don't think we have an issues with firewall but we had network related issues even with normal Kafka consumer. In generally confluent Kafka module. Is there any way to handle this in PySpark environment?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if the regular Kafka CLI tools (or other Kafka clients) aren't working, then I wouldn't expect Spark to work either

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What i want to say is when we use kafka-python library, some times our consumer stops. However after we move to confluent kafka library and mad some changes in configuration (as an example increase request time out time) the issue was almost fixed. Is there any configurations we want to look at?

Comment: The only things I can think of would be that the leader partition for the topic came offline (maybe temporarily). If you have at least three replicas for the topic and no under-replicated partitions, that should be transparently handled by Spark